# Wireshark не отлавливает http запросы

Tags: windows, http, kali-linux, wireshark

Изначально проблема была на виртуальной машине с `kali linux`. Я выбирал сетевой интерфейс `ethernet` (у него у единственного график скакал, когда я переходил по сайтам). Потом с включенным захватом пакетов я перешел на [сайт](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) и ожидал в `wireshark` по фильтру `http` 2 запроса, запрос на получение страницы и ответ со статусом 200, но ничего не отлавливается.

Решил попробовать на `windows` и на нем я уже выбираю беспроводную сеть (т.к. сижу через ноутбук с `wifi`), и та же проблема. График есть, а `http` запросы не отлавливаются.

В чем может быть проблема и как её решить?

Comment: Может потому что сайты по https?

Comment: @AlexeyTen логично), а как тогда отлавливать пакеты https? У меня фильтра https нет в wireshark

Comment: А с https всё гораздо сложнее. Можете попробовать Fiddler или mitmproxy.

Comment: @zed да я погуглил и увидел, что чтобы увидеть https запросы, нужно в фильтре написать tls. Так же там целая схема как происходит соединение. Клиент здоровается, сервер обмен ключами происходит и т.д. Так что не получится просто взять и посмотреть данные.

Comment: @Bonifacy, а Вы и не посмотрите эти данные, даже если предпримите какие-то усилия, название фильтра `tls` Вам ни чего не говорит? Протокол шифрования данных, который работает поверх протокола http...

Если Вам интересно как отслеживается протокол http, обратитесь к библиотеке Python `Scapy`, создайте пакет и отправьте его по локальной сети.

Comment: @AlexRebell не уверен конечно, но вроде вы не правы. Данные переданные по https можно спокойно просмотреть в wireshark. На сколько я понял это работает так: заходим на сайт и у нас начинается соединение с сервером, ну и логично что мы получаем ключ для расшифровки данных (иначе как сайт открывается на моём компьютере) и вот эти данные для расшифровки в wireshark мы и можем использовать.